# Cropping Occupancy Grid Maps directly from msg.Data

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to compare two occupancy grid maps "at runtime", a ground truth map and a map generated from multirobot map merge. The reason I want to crop the generated map is because the map produced by multirobot_map_merge does not have the same dimensions or center with me maps that it merges, they are slightly off. Let's say that I have a 480x480 map.
Does anyone know how I can crop this map (edit the tuple  given by gm message) to 450x450?
I tried making the tuple into a 2d list so it can be more intuitive and then flatten it again but it doesn't work. Has anyone done this before? I would appreciate some tips.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402315/cropping-occupancy-grid-maps-directly-from-msg.data/) by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2022-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map is published as a list. First convert that list to a `numpy` array so it'll be easier for you to play with it.

Create a new numpy zero/ones array of whatever height X width you want and copy the corresponding elements from original map array to it.

---

Originally posted by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) with karma: 277 on 2022-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First from your map_msg create a numpy array then reshape it by using height and width.

You can then use the bellow functions (taken from a class, you might need to modify it a bit):

```
def find_bounds(self):
    """
    Calculates the bounding box of a map array
    """
    map = self.occupancy_grid
    a = np.where(map != -1)
    bbox = np.min(a[0]), np.max(a[0]), np.min(a[1]), np.max(a[1])
    return Bounds(bbox[0], bbox[1], bbox[2], bbox[3])

def get_submap(self):
    """
    Retrieve the filled sub map that's contained inside the map array
    """
    self.sub_map_bounds = self.find_bounds()
    return self.occupancy_grid[self.sub_map_bounds.xmin:self.sub_map_bounds.xmax+1, self.sub_map_bounds.ymin:self.sub_map_bounds.ymax+1]
```

---

Originally posted by [Alex-SSoM](https://answers.ros.org/users/86099/alex-ssom/) with karma: 163 on 2022-06-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on 2022-06-15**:
Thanks , i fixed my problem already, but the general idea is similar tou yours.
The problem in my implementation was that i was searching the 2d array column-wise and not row-wise as the occupancy grid msg says. Moral of the story: read the documentation carefully.